# Distribution of Weighted Sample Variance

Tags: random-variable, gamma-distribution, weighted-mean, weighted-data

Say we have $N$ independent Gaussian variables $X_i$, each drawn from a mean-zero Gaussian with variance $\sigma_i^2$, where in this case I assume I know the $\sigma_i^2$. Define the weighted average as

$$
  \bar{X} = w \sum_i^N X_i / \sigma_i^2, \ \ w = \left(\sum_i^N \sigma^{-2}_i\right)^{-1}.
$$

Then define the weighted sample variance as

$$
  S^2 = w \sum_i^N (X_i - \bar{X})^2 / \sigma_i^2
$$

In the case that all variances are equal, so that $\sigma_i^2 = \sigma_2$, this is of course just the standard un-weighted sample variance.

Now, the expectation of $S^2$ is simply $w(N-1)$, where the $(N-1)$ comes about in the same way that we get it in the non-weighted case. We can then consider the quantity $\gamma = S^2 / \langle S^2 \rangle$ to be a "normalized" weighted variance with expectation unity.
**I'd like to know the distribution of $\gamma$**.

In the case that all variances are equal, $\gamma$ can be written

$$
  \gamma = \frac{N}{N-1} \sum_i^N (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2,
$$

where $Y = X/\sigma$ is a standard normally distributed variable. According to [this MathWorld article](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SampleVarianceDistribution.html), this ends up having the distribution

$$
      f(\gamma) = \frac{\beta^\beta}{\Gamma(\beta)} \gamma^{\beta-1} e^{-\beta \gamma},
$$

with $\beta = (N-1)/2$. This is just a Gamma distribution.

But what about the case in which $\sigma_i^2$ can vary for different $i$? Having run several simulations, it *seems* that the distribution of $\gamma$ is precisely the same as in the unweighted case, and thus depends only on $N$. I have only two problems with this:

1. I can't prove it.
2. Intuitively, I would expect that if I had say $N=100$, but of those variables, only one had low variance, and the rest had "enormously" high variance, then the distribution should be approximately the same as having $N=1$. However, the distribution knows nothing about the variances involved, and only about the total number of observations. Most likely my intuition just needs to be sharpened here -- does anyone have a good explanation?

**EDIT**
I'm adding some code and a plot here to show the simulation I did:

So, here's the simulation code:

```py
def simulate(variance: np.ndarray, size=100000):
    nd = len(variance)
    w = 1/np.sum(1/variance)
    
    Z = np.random.normal(size=(size, nd))
    first_term = np.sum(Z**2, axis=1)
    second_term = np.sum(Z / np.sqrt(variance), axis=1)**2 * w
    return (first_term - second_term) / (nd - 1)
```

Then, I made a plot where I used three different variance vectors: (i) all ones, (ii) all ones except one at $10^{-5}$, and (iii) half ones, half $10^{-5}$.

Code for making the plot:

```py
N = 100

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
sim_gamma_ones = simulate(np.ones(N))

lopsided_var = np.ones(N)
lopsided_var[0] /= 1e5  # very small variance for just one observation
sim_gamma_single_good = simulate(lopsided_var)


half_var = np.ones(N)
half_var[:N//2] /= 1e5  # very small variance for just one observation
sim_gamma_half_good = simulate(half_var)


plt.hist(sim_gamma_ones, bins=150, histtype='step', label='unweighted', density=True)
plt.hist(sim_gamma_single_good, bins=150, histtype='step', label='one reliable obs', density=True)
plt.hist(sim_gamma_half_good, bins=150, histtype='step', label='half reliable', density=True)

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 500)
plt.plot(x, gamma.pdf(x, a=(N-1)/2, scale=2/(N-1)), color='k', lw=1, label='Gamma distribution')

plt.title(f"N={N}")

plt.legend()
```

The plots:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you considered varying the $\sigma_i$ *extremely*? For instance, consider a large number of $X_i$ with $\sigma_i\ll 1$ and an equally large number with $\sigma_i=1.$ It's an easy simulation to do and you should be shocked at the result.  BTW, it's hard to find a theoretical justification for your weighting of the SD.  What are you hoping it represents?

Comment: Thank you @whuber, yes I have considered varying $\sigma_i$ extremely. I have added a plot and related code to the OP to show what I have done. The results are surprising, in that they don't fit with my stated intuition, but that is why I asked this question :-) 

The weighting on the sample variance essentially represents counts of observations. In my case, each $X_i$ is actually an (unweighted) average of $N_i$ observations, each of which is expected to be drawn from the same Gaussian distribution (and independent). In practice, my weights are the $N_i$.

Comment: My concern is that your weights likely do not reflect the full uncertainties that should be considered.  By accounting *only* for the counts, your model effectively supposes there is no other form of uncertainty in your model.  As a result, you might be giving far too much weight to the high-count results.  But one thing is certain from this little experiment: your conjecture that the weights don't affect the distribution of $\gamma$ is incorrect.

Comment: I am certain that there are other uncertainties in the model -- partly, the aim of knowing this distribution is to diagnose the extra uncertainties. 

I am a little confused as to why you say that it's incorrect that the weights don't affect the distribution of $\gamma$? It seems to me that the simulation shows that the distribution is insensitive to the weights? It only cares about $N$, not $\sigma_i$?

Comment: Simulate with $N=2.$

Comment: Your $S^2$ without the '$w$' is already a weighted sample variance, and that has a standard distribution.

Comment: I've added the $N=2$ plot (with yscale in log) to the OP. It still seems to tell me that the Gamma function is good for both weighted and unweighted. I feel like I'm missing something!
@StubbornAtom I would have thought there would be a standard distribution, but I have not found one in my search so far. Do you have a link?

Comment: I mean $\sum_{i=1}^N (X_i - \bar{X})^2 / \sigma_i^2$ is already a weighted sample variance, and this has a chi-square distribution: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3563361/321264.

Comment: I see, thank you, that gives me exactly what I was looking for. I'm sorry I didn't see that question/answer previously.